# Why updateOne doesn't update my collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I tried to update a document on my MongoDB Atlas collection from a form.

I use Node.js, MongoDB Driver and bodyParser.

```
app.post("/quotes", (req, res) => {

    client.connect(err => {
        const db = client.db("test");
        const userID = {$eq: {"userID" : (req.body.userID)}}
        const update = {$set: {"name": (req.body.name)}}
        db.collection("customers").updateOne(userID, update, function(err, res) {
            console.log("POST /quotes");
            client.close();
        });
    });
    res.redirect("/user");

});
```

They expected output is a updated document in my collection, but the actual output is in my console log.

My console log:

```
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
the options [srvHost] is not supported
the options [credentials] is not supported
```

Comment: did you set the userID yourself or is it perhaps mongo's built in `ObjectId` ? if it is then you would have to change `req.body.userID` to `new ObjectId(req.body.userID)`

Comment: The userID is set by myself. It can be called "username".

Comment: When I remove the app.post and change the req.body.something by a value, everything is working in my console. But, the goal is to fetch with body-parser the form and put in MongoDB.

Comment: can you show us what's the output of `console.log(req.body)` ?

Answer (score 0):

the userId type is String in the req.body then you have to convert it to ObjectId

```
 const mongo = require('mongodb');

 app.post("/quotes", (req, res) => {
 client.connect(err => {
    const db = client.db("test");


    try {
       mongoId = new mongo.ObjectId(req.body.userID);
    } catch (err) {
       if (err) return res.send({ error: err });
    }

    const userID = {$eq: {"userID" : (mongoId)}}
    const update = {$set: {"name": (req.body.name)}}
    db.collection("customers").updateOne(userID, update, function(err, res) {
        console.log("POST /quotes");
        client.close();
    });
   });
   res.redirect("/user");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found!

```
app.post("/quotes", (req, res) => {

    client.connect(err => {
        const db = client.db("test");
        const userID = {$eq: {"userID" : (req.body.userID)}}
        const update = {$set: {"name": (req.body.name)}}
        db.collection("customers").updateOne(userID, update, function(err, res) {
            console.log("POST /quotes");
        });
    });
    client.close();
    res.redirect("/user");

});
```

The `client.close();`must be outside the function.